# Poisson calculation (erlang C)

Tags: c, poisson

i posted this before, user told me to post it on codereview. i did, and they closed it...so one more time here: (i deleted the old question)

I have these formulas:

[image]

and I need the Poisson formulas for the erlangC formula:

[image]

I tried to rebuild the formulas in C:

```
double getPoisson(double m, double u, bool cumu)
{
    double ret = 0;
    if(!cumu)
    {
        ret = (exp(-u)*pow(u,m)) / (factorial(m));
    }
    else
    {
        double facto = 1;
        double ehu = exp(-u);
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            ret = ret + (ehu * pow(u,i)) / facto;
            facto *= (i+1);
        }
     }
     return ret;
}
```

The Erlang C Formula:

```
double getErlangC(double m, double u, double p)
{
    double numerator = getPoisson(m, u, false);
    double denominator = getPoisson(m, u, false) + (1-p) * getPoisson(m, u, true);
    return numerator/denominator;
}
```

The main problem is, the `m` parameter in `getPoisson` is a big value (>170)
so it wants to calculate >170! but it cannot handle it.  I think the primitive data types are too small to work correctly, or what do you say?

BTW: This is the factorial function I use for the first Poisson:

```
double factorial(double n)
{
    if(n >= 1)
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Some samples:

Input:

```
double l = getErlangC(50, 48, 0.96);
printf("%g", l);
```

Output:

```
0.694456 (correct)
```

Input:

```
double l = getErlangC(100, 96, 0.96);
printf("%g", l);
```

Output:

```
0.5872811 (correct)
```

if i use a value higher than 170 for the first parameter (m) of getErlangC like:

Input:

```
double l = getErlangC(500, 487, 0.974);
printf("%g", l);
```

Output:

```
naN (incorrect)
```

Excepted:

```
0.45269
```

How's my approach? Would be there a better way to calculate Poisson and erlangC?

Some Info: Excel has the POISSON Function, and on Excel it works perfekt... would there be a way to see the algorithm(code) EXCEL uses for POISSON?

Comment: If the question was closed or not answered to your satisfaction, don't repost it!

Comment: ["The conventional definition of the Poisson distribution contains two terms that can easily overflow on computers: λk and k!. The fraction of λk to k! can also produce a rounding error which is very large compared to e−λ, and therefore give an erroneous result."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Definition) I'm sure you've  spent a lot of time on this.

Comment: you didnt understand it..closed on Codereview @Olaf

Comment: "i posted this before, ..." - No, you posted it here first, then code review, now here again!

Comment: Did you not read the comments last time? There should be no need to calculate that stupendous factorial. The running term of your series can be multiplied by `u` and divided by `k`, then added to the series sum (ref. the second formula in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107616/how-to-calculate-erlangc-poisson-in-c-program)).

Comment: I cant follow you :/ could u show me that as code?  I have the same problem in the first poisson function (bool = false)@WeatherVane

Comment: Each term `k` has `u^k / k!`. So each term is the previous term times `u` over `k`.

Comment: ...and be aware that `0!` for the first term (your series starts from `k=0`) is `1`, so there is no div 0  error.

Comment: i still cant follow you, a code line would be better to understand @WeatherVane

Comment: To write your code for you would have to be an answer, and since I cannot guarantee that writing your code will produce the answers you need, I can only say that if you are not just blindly copying code, you have enough information now to write it yourself.

Comment: Lets start with post text, not images,  Most of us could probably help you, if 1) you posted text 2) you were clear, in your question, about exactly what it the problem\

Comment: voting to close because you did not follow the rules about posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(pow(u, m)/factorial(m))` can be expressed as a recursive loop with each element shown as u/n where each n is an element of m!.

```
double ratio(double u, int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
     {
        // Avoid the ratio overflow by calculating each ratio element
        double val;
        val = u/n;
        return val*ratio(u, n-1);
      }
    else
      {
         // Avoid division by 0 as power and factorial of 0 are 1
        return 1;
      }
}
```

Note that if you want to avoid recursion, you can do it as a loop as well

```
double ratio(double u, int n)
{
    int i;
    // Avoid the ratio overflow by calculating each ratio element
    // default the ratio to 1 for n == 0
    double val = 1;
    // calculate the next n-1 ratios and put them into the total
    for (i = 1; i<=n; i++)
      {
        // Put in the next element of the ratio 
        val *=  u/i;
      }
    // return the final value of the ratio
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Infinite descent, stack overflow, undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate, misleading indentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i used your way, and now i can handle big values

Comment: @EOF Thank you for pointing out the typo of leaving out the brackets. With the brackets in, the result is not infinite. Sice val is used only inside the if, I moved the definition into that scope and the values are no longer indeterminate.

Comment: The control variable of a recursion typically is an integer type. I don't see any reason to use a float here, but very good reasons not to.

Comment: @Olaf good point. Since it is a power and a factorial then you are correct. I will fix it.

Comment: @T.Setso Thank you for letting me know it worked. I do not have access to a compiler.

Comment: Thanks to you! you helped me alot :) btw; u added a iterative way. What reasons should i have to use iterativ and not recursiv? @sabbahillel

Comment: What reasons should i have to use the iterativ way and not recursiv?@sabbahillel

Comment: @T.Setso no particular reason. I put it in for completeness. However, on some systems the stack processing could be worse than the looping. I just like to show the looping equivalent of recursion at times for completeness. I have spoken to some people who would otherwise have to have the recursion explained in more detail. This way someone else seeing the answer can see the expansion as part of the answer.

Comment: ok, i tried the iterative way, and the return value is false :) anyway the recursive way works! @sabbahillel

Comment: @chux Yes it was a typo.Thanks for seeing it.

Comment: @T.Setso yes, the `u/n` in the iterative code was a typo. It was supposed to be `u/i`

Answer (score 1):

To cope with values exceeding the `double` range, re-code to use the *log* of values.  Downside- some precision loss.

Precision can be re-gained with improved code, but here is something that at least copes with the range issues.

Slight variant of OP's code follows: Used for comparison.

```
long double factorial(unsigned m) {
  long double f = 1.0;
  while (m > 0) {
    f *= m;
    m--;
  }
  return f;
}

double getPoisson(unsigned m, double u, bool cumu) {
  double ret = 0;
  if (!cumu) {
    ret = (double) ((exp(-u) * pow(u, m)) / (factorial(m)));
  } else {
    double facto = 1;
    double ehu = exp(-u);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      ret = ret + (ehu * pow(u, i)) / facto;
      facto *= (i + 1);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

double getErlang(unsigned m, double u, double p) {
  double numerator = getPoisson(m, u, false);
  double denominator = numerator + (1.0 - p) * getPoisson(m, u, true);
  return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Suggested changes

```
#ifdef M_PI
  #define  MY_PI M_PI
#else
  #define  MY_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif

// log of n!
//
// Gosper Approximation of Stirling's Approximation
// http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html
// n! about= sqrt(pi*(2*n + 1/3.)) * pow(n,n)  * exp(-n)
static double ln_factorial(unsigned n) {
  if (n <= 1) return 0.0;
  double x = n;
  return log(sqrt(MY_PI * (2 * x + 1 / 3.0))) + log(x) * x - x;
}


double getPoisson_2(unsigned m, double u, bool cumu) {
  double ret = 0.0;
  if (cumu) {
    // Simplify term calculation.  `mul` does not get too large nor small.
    double mul = exp(-u);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      ret += mul;
      mul *= u/(i + 1);
      // printf("ret:% 10e  mul:% 10e\n", ret, mul);
    }
  } else {
    // ret = (exp(-u) * pow(u, m)) / (factorial(m));
    double ln_ret = -u + log(u) * m - ln_factorial(m);
    return exp(ln_ret);
  }
  return ret;
}

double getErlang_2(unsigned m, double u, double p) {
  double numerator = getPoisson_2(m, u, false);
  double denominator = numerator + (1 - p) * getPoisson_2(m, u, true);
  return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Test code

```
void ErTest(unsigned m, double u, double p, double expect) {
  printf("m:%4u  u:% 14e  p:% 14e", m, u, p);
  printf("  E0:% 14e", expect);
  double y1 = getErlang(m, u, p);
  printf("  E1:% 14e", y1);
  double y2 = getErlang_2(m, u, p);
  printf("  E2:% 14e", y2);
  puts("");
}

int main(void) {
  ErTest(50, 48, 0.96, 0.694456);
  ErTest(100, 96, 0.96, 0.5872811);
  ErTest(500, 487, 0.974, 0.45269);
}

m:  50  u:  4.800000e+01  p:  9.600000e-01  E0:  6.944560e-01  E1:  6.944556e-01  E2:  6.944562e-01
m: 100  u:  9.600000e+01  p:  9.600000e-01  E0:  5.872811e-01  E1:  5.872811e-01  E2:  5.872813e-01
m: 500  u:  4.870000e+02  p:  9.740000e-01  E0:  4.526900e-01  E1:           nan  E2:  4.464746e-01
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your help. Your algorithm is wonderful, i just tried the algorithm of "sabbahillel" and its shorter than yours, but gives exactly the same results. Iam going to understand what u guys did, and then i am going to implement it! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your large recursive `factorial` is a problem as it might produce a stack overflow as well as a value overflow. `pow` might also get large.

Here's a way to combine things incrementally:

```
double
getPoisson(double m, double u, bool cumu)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double facto = 1;
    double u_i = 1;
    double ehu = exp(-u);
    double cur = ehu;

    // u_i -- pow(u,i)
    // cur -- current/last term in series
    // sum -- sum of terms

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cur = (ehu * u_i) / facto;
        sum += cur;

        u_i *= u;
        facto *= (i + 1);
    }

    return cumu ? sum : cur;
}
```

The above is "okay", but still might overflow some values because of the `u_i` and `facto` terms.

Here is an alternate that combines the terms as a ratio. It is less likely to overflow:

```
double
getPoisson(double m, double u, bool cumu)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double ehu = exp(-u);
    double cur = ehu;
    double ratio = 1;

    // cur -- current/last term in series
    // sum -- sum of terms
    // ratio -- u^i / factorial(i)

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cur = ehu * ratio;
        sum += cur;

        ratio *= u;
        ratio /= (i + 1);
    }

    return cumu ? sum : cur;
}
```

The above might *still* produce some large values. If so, you might have to use `long double`, `quadmath`, or multiprecision arithmetic. Or, come up with an "analog" of the equation/algorithm.

Comment: I tried your `getPoisson()` as a replacement for OP's `getPoisson()` with `getErlang(50, 48, .96)` and was about 1.2% off,  not too bad.  Although I'd expect better - perhaps OP's numbers are off?  Maybe the test harness of my answer may help compare.

Comment: @chux Thanks [and thank the stars]. I coded it [pre-coffee :-)], based upon some prior code I had done for Taylor series. I was treating it as a reference example and didn't test it. I desk checked it a few times, so I was pretty sure about it, but it's nice to know it worked "out-of-the-box".

Comment: Hey Craig Estey, thanks for your help :) as chux said, the return value is a little bit differ :)) Anyway. Thanks! @CraigEstey

Comment: `ratio *= u; ratio /= (i + 1);` --> `ratio *= u/(i + 1);` may help range issues.

Comment: @chux On the `ratio` calc, the optimizer might handle it. But, I'll give it a try. Also, you _had_ a comment about `cumu` vs. not. I took a look and the code _may_ need to increment `m` before the loop for the non-cumu case. I'm going out for [much needed] coffee, so I'll fix this all later. Your thoughts?

Comment: Further checking. `getPoisson( m,  u, cumu==false)` is wrong (At least it differs from EXCEL which matches OP's expectations), not by too much, but by more than should be.

Comment: When `(cumu == 0)` I think you want `double cur = 1; ... for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      ratio *= u/(i + 1);
        cur = ehu * ratio;
        sum += cur; }`  This is very close to Excel.  This may not be good when `cumu==true`